# Can I aim the cannons in chalice dungeons

Tags: bloodborne

Going through chalice dungeons I occasionally find cannons that seem to be manned by enemies. It seems like they can shoot them wherever they want. However if I go up to a cannon I get an option to "Operate Device" but it only seems to fire the cannon in a fixed trajectory.

Is there any way to aim the cannon where you want to or are you limited to just where its fixed arc points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Additionally, neither can the enemies that are manning them. The only reason it appears they can hit you over a large area, is because the cannons themselves have an extremely large AoE.

Comment: There's also several occasions where the cannons will detonate explosive jars, adding to their AoE.